# Javascript storing data

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am a beginner web developer and am trying to build the interface of a simple e-commerce site as a personal project.The site has **multiple pages with checkboxes**.

When someone checks an element

- it retrives the price of the element and
- stores it in a variable.

But when I go to the next page and **click on new checkboxes** products the variable automaticly **resets** to its original state.

How can I save the value of that variable in Javascript?I am using the **jQuery** library.

EDIT:This is the code I've writen using sessionStorage but it still dosen't work when I move to next page the value is reseted.

How can I wright this code so that i dosen't reset on each page change.All pages on my website use the same script.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
         var total = 0;



            $('input.check').click(function(){
                if($(this).attr('checked')){
                    var check = parseInt($(this).parent().children('span').text().substr(1 , 3));
                    total+=check;
                    sessionStorage.var_name=0 + total;
                    alert(sessionStorage.var_name);

                }else{
                    var uncheck = parseInt($(this).parent().children('span').text().substr(1 , 3));
                    total-=uncheck;


                }
            })
```

Comment: How do you go to next page via AJAX or page reload?

Comment: Cookies are always another option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax for `sessionStorage` is simple, and it retains it's data until the browser window is closed. It acts exactly like any other javascript object. You can use dot-notation or square bracket notation (required for keys with spaces) to access stored values.

**Storing values using `sessionStorage`**

```
sessionStorage['value key'] = 'value to store';
```

**Using stored values**

```
alert(sessionStorage['value key']);  // Alerts "value to store".
```

Comment: I have tryed using sessionStorage but it seems the data keeps reseting can you take a look at the code I've writen ?

Comment: try using localStorage in place of sessionStorage and report me what happened

Comment: same thing the moment I change the link to go to the next page of my website the value is reseted

Comment: Check for browser support by this code
if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
   {
   // Yes! localStorage and sessionStorage support!
   // Some code.....
   }
 else
   {
   // Sorry! No web storage support..
   }

Comment: I am using the latest version of firefox already checked for support it is support either I am not writing the code right or something else is the problem

Comment: BTW why are you adding 0 to total as adding 0 will not affect total's value

Answer (score 2):

You could use localStorage to acomplish this. You'd need to set up a fallback for it, using localStorage however could be done like this:

Reading from storage:

```
if (localStorage['valueName'] !== undefined) {
    input.value = localStorage['valueName'];
}
```

Writing to storage:

```
localStorage['valueName'] = input.value;
```

Here's a jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/yJjLe/

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned above you can use `sessionStorage` or `localStorage`. Another option available is [`HTML5 Web Databases`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm)
And take a look at [this presentation](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/html5storage/index.html).

Also keep in mind that html5 web storage is not secure as anyone can see your stored data simply from the console.